# Initialization class member using initializer list results a memory leak

Tags: c++

I have a class that contains an attribute char * variable name that points to an allocated char array from new char[] that contains a C style text string. I'm using overloaded constructor that has attribute char[] variable name_val and is equal to "emtpy".In member initialization list, i have initialized  private class member name to nullptr and, inside of a constructor, I have allocated space for it depending on size of name_val, copied it to name using strcpy. When I compile program i get warning that says,
[Warning] deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings].I am also seeing a memory leak. So i spent little time messing around and as soon as I set the char name_val to const char name_val[]="empty", inside overloaded constructor everything works perfectly fine.

Here is the code, and note that,inside of overloaded constructor the attribute  char[] variable name name_ val  is not set as const!

Can someone please explain, what is the purpose of const in this case?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;

class Person{
    char *name;
public:
    Person(char name_val[]="empty"):
        name{nullptr}{
            name=new char[strlen(name_val)+1];
            strcpy(name,name_val);
        }
    ~Person(){
        delete [] name;name=nullptr;
    }

    char *get_Name()const{return name;}
};

int main(){

    Person p;
    cout<<p.get_Name()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: String literals like `"empty"` could be stored in read only memory. If you point at it with a non-const pointer, you open the door for nonsense like `name_val[0] = 'X';`, and Crom only knows what kind of bad smurf will go down trying to make that write.

Comment: How do you know you have a memory leak?

Answer (score 2):

> Initialization class member using initializer list results a memory leak
>
> I am also seeing a memory leak.

There is no memory leak in the shown program. It is unclear why you would think that you see it.

> Can someone please explain, what is the purpose of const in this case?

Object being const means that its state (except for mutable members in case of class types) cannot be modified. Pointer / reference to const means that the pointed / referred object may not be modified through the pointer / reference.

A pointer to non-const can implicitly be converted to pointer to const, but the conversion back is not implicit.

String literals are const. A pointer to non-const (`char*`) cannot be assigned to point to a const object since C++11. The warning message that you see implies that you're using a pre C++11 version of C++. Back then conversion from string literal to `char*` was well-formed, but the conversion was deprecated.

---

P.S. `Person` has a serious design flaw: The class is copyable, but if you ever make a copy intentionally, or incidentally, the behaviour of the program will be undefined.

P.P.S. The default member initialiser is redundant, since you never use it.

Answer (score 0):

When you write:

```
Person(char name_val[]="empty")
```

it is equivalent to writing:

```
Person(char *name_val="empty")
```

and now you can see that you are assigning a string constant to non-const `char *`, hence the warning.  The solution (obviously) is to write:

```
Person(const char *name_val="empty")
```

and then the compiler will be happy.

OTOH, when you write:

```
Person()
{
    char name_val[]="empty"
    ...
}
```

then you are creating a character array on the stack and copying the given string constant into it, so no `const` is required (although it would still be a good idea in this instance).

I don't know why you think you have a memory leak.  I don't see one in your code.

Comment: When I compile, sometimes returns zero value and sometimes crashes, maybe it was typo mistake while I was writing code, anyways thank you, finally got the point